# Reading MS Access database in windows with ruby from mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, macos, ms-access

I have a rails application running on mac and an MS Access database located on windows server PC which data are changing daily. 
Both may mac and windows PC are in the same network and also I have permission to connect to server remotely by telnet.
How may I just read data from my mac using ruby to publish it?

Answer (score 0):

In database.yml, you should configure the db parameter, like adapter, host, port, username, password. I am not sure if there is Access DB adapter for Rails. And then, you can create your models corresponding to the DB tables. Please refer to [this](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/web-development/ruby/9780596510329/database/connecting_to_multiple_databases)

I did the almost same thing, except I use Sqlite tables in local host and PSQL tables in remote server in development. Ater you finish the configure and models creation, you can use the model as normal, almost no any difference.